# Socket.io issue while using leapjs-rigged-hand

Tags: javascript, socket.io, leap-motion

I am working on making an interface for a Leap motion controlled robot. From the server side node.js, I am emitting an event 'action' which contains the data to be displayed on a HTML page. I am using leapjs-rigged-hand for visualization
(https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs-rigged-hand)

```
  <body>
      <div id="display"><span id="direction">undefined</span></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('action', function(data) {
              $('$display').html(data);
        });

        var controller = new Leap.Controller;
        (controller).use('riggedHand', {
              scale: 1.5
        })
        .connect();

        controller.on('riggedHand.meshAdded', function(handMesh, leapHand){
              handMesh.material.opacity = 1;
              handMesh.material.color.set('#7b4b2a');
              handMesh.material.ambient = handMesh.material.color;
        });
  </script>
```

Shown above is the relevant part of the code. The problem is that socket callback works only before the first "riggedHand.meshAdded" event is fired.

How do I make them work simultaneously?

Comment: Your socket and your Leap controller are two different things and should not affect each other. Maybe your display `div` is getting covered by the Leap canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Initialized controller with {background: true} on both the client and the server side